# deploy program including external libraries

Tags: c#, deployment, .net-4.0, publishing

I have this application that uses external libraries (downloaded them from the Internet and are just situated locally on my machine). But I need to deploy the program and give it to customer whereas these external libraries should also be included in the deployed application, otherwise it won't work...

Should I just copy the library files in the project directory and then publish the project or something else?

p.s. the application is written in C# with .NET 4 on VS2010, and the external libraries are open source, so no worries on the license.

Comment: What programming language? What IDE? What licenses do the external libraries have?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to mention that. I made an Edit.

Comment: Cool, I've added relevant tags to help people find your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you are using some flavour of visual studio.

If so, you need to set library "copy local" property to true.

See [this Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew%28VS.80%29.aspx) for more information

This way, when you build the project, it will make a copy of all of the required libraries in the bin folder of the project.